# Excel wont accept SelfCert Digital certificate

Tags: excel, vba, certificate-store

I have just moved machine from Windows 8.1/office 2010  to Win 10/Office 2019. I have an Excel spreadsheet with a lot of VBA code. Excel 2019 wont accept the old certificate so I am having to re-certificate the sheet.

In the Trust Centre
The options are set to "Disable all macros except digitally signed macros"
As far as I am able the trust centre settings in the two offices are set the same.

I have created a new certificate on the Windows 10 machine. (MyCert)
I have tried installing it as per microsoft's guide. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01)

But the protected view and the Enable editing messages persist.

I have tried removing the certificate saving the file; then adding the certificate and saving it again - without effect.

The certificate shows as having been added and appears in the dialog box. Both under Signed as and sign as parts of the dialog box.

The certificate is not in the trusted store but I could not see how to use mmc (certificate addin) to add it.

I realise that I am making a simple mistake but I cant see how to get Excel to recognise the certificate and I wonder if anyone can help?

Comment: Did you try to copy or move to the trusted store.?